# How do I find, count and print to the page the number of occurrences of a text string

Tags: jquery

How can jquery find, count and print to the page, the number of occurrences of `'<lineNo'` that exist inside a div 
called `'dialogue'` and do so without replacing all the text on the page?

```
<div id="dialogue">
<div id="1">
 <lineNo1>1</lineNo1>) 
 <lineNo2>2</lineNo2>) 
 <lineNo3>3</lineNo3>) 
</div>

<div id="2">
 <lineNo1>1</lineNo1>) 
 <lineNo2>2</lineNo2>) 
 <lineNo3>3</lineNo3>) 
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: why are you using xml mixed with html? Will have cross browser problems

Comment: It's an internal admin page, thus not in danger of this. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***HTML***

```
<div id="dialogue">
    <div id="1">
     <lineNo1>1</lineNo1>) 
     <lineNo2>2</lineNo2>) 
     <lineNo3>3</lineNo3>) 
    </div>

    <div id="2">
     <lineNo1>1</lineNo1>) 
     <lineNo2>2</lineNo2>) 
     <lineNo3>3</lineNo3>) 
    </div>

    <!-- display line no -->
    <div class="msg">You have <span class="count"></span> lines.</div>

</div>​ <!-- Missing this closing in question -->
```

***jQuery***

```
var count = 0;;
$('div[id^="dialogue"] div').each(function() {
    var pattern = new RegExp('<lineNo', 'ig'),
        match = $(this).html().match(pattern),
        len = match ? match.length : 0;
        count += len; 
});
$('.msg span.count').html(count);
```

***[​DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gwhmz/3/)***
    ​

Comment: Outstanding! Works right out of the box. Thank you. Is there a way to print to the page without triggering the page rewrite or the alert?

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER yeap.. please check the update with demo

Comment: Got it! Thank you CodeParadox!

Answer (score 1):

To get the text within a div, use the jQuery selector: `$('.dialogue').text()`

You can then get all occurrences of a string using a regex: `someString.match(/lineNo/g)`

Comment: The system won't let me upvote you since I don't have a 15 rep, but thanks for your input Fiona.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use `document.write`.

```
$("body").append("<div>" + $("#dialogue *").filter(function () {
   return this.nodeName.toUpperCase().indexOf('LINENO') > -1; 
}).length + "</div>");​
```

This simply creates a new div and appends it to the body.  Its content is the count you desire.  Note that this may not play nice with IE8-, which handles unknown nodes in an unusual fashion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I should ask more clearly perhaps. I don't understand the use of append since I'm want to count them and have the page tell me how many times `<lineNo`  occurs so I can compare that number to the data that was entered into the db.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER `.append` just puts the count somewhere on the page .. you could use `console.log` or `alert` if you wanted

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks for following up. Oddly, I have a document.write on the page that isn't overwriting everything but I'm so new to jquery I can't understand why. Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't yet have a 15 reputation so my upvotes are not recorded. Will my personal thanks do in the meantime? Thank you.